# how to create a list in todo app more than one time (only javascript)

Tags: javascript

i move `var liElement = document.createElement('li');` out side the function `addTodo()`  to make this function work

```
 function removeTodo(){
    liElement.remove()
};
```

but now i have another problem that is i can't add more than one todo (li)

```
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
const todoList = document.getElementById('todoList');
var ulElement = document.createElement('ul');
var liElement = document.createElement('li');
let placeholderValue = '';
```

// This code is for clear placeholder value

```
input.addEventListener('focus' , () => {
    placeholderValue = input.placeholder;
    input.placeholder = '';
});

input.addEventListener('blur' , ()=> {
    input.placeholder = placeholderValue;
});
```

// this function is for add to do to a list

```
function addTodo(){
    todoList.appendChild(ulElement)
    ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
    liElement.classList.add('liElement')
    liElement.innerHTML = input.value;
};
addBtn.addEventListener('click' , addTodo)
// this function is for remove todo from the list
function removeTodo(){
    liElement.remove()
};
liElement.addEventListener('contextmenu' , (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    removeTodo()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `createTextNode` for example :

```js
 var t = document.createTextNode(input.value);
   liElement.appendChild(t);
```

...and you have builded a very complex structure. Make it easier for yourself.

**And finally**

```
const todoList = document.getElementById('todoList');
var ulElement = document.createElement('ul');
```

why use to createElements ? you don't need these.  You can create them in html file.

Comment: Thank you! I was reviewing my old question and i noticed that i didn't give you the 'correct answer mark' , sorry for that bro <3